# OpenLDAP cannot add new schema

Tags: ldap, openldap, schema

I'm trying to add new schema to my OpenLDAP server. The version of slapd is 2.4.23. I'm using Debian 6.

If I understood it well, slapd 2.4+ uses OLC configuration with (cn=config) by default for this version and I don't have to modify anything in slapd.conf or some other point in the cn=config tree (am I wrong?). But when I'm trying to add schema with following command:

```
ldapadd -x -D "cn=admin,cn=config" -W -f filesystem.ldif
```

it gives me:

```
Enter LDAP Password: 
ldap_bind: Invalid credentials (49)
```

I also tried this command(even if I don't know what I'm doing here):

```
ldapadd -x -D "cn=admin,dc=linuxcbt,dc=internal" -W -f filesystem.ldif
```

where dc=linuxcbt,dc=internal is my base, I get:

```
adding new entry "cn=filesystem,cn=schema,cn=config"
ldap_add: Insufficient access (50)
```

My filesystem.ldif file is:

```
dn: cn=filesystem,cn=schema,cn=config
objectClass: olcSchemaConfig
cn: filesystem

olcAttributeTypes: ( 1000.1.1.1 NAME ( 'fn' 'filename' )
   DESC 'Nome del file'
   EQUALITY 'Case exact match'
   SUBSTR caseExactSubstringsMatch
   SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.15 )

olcAttributeTypes: ( 1000.1.1.2 NAME ( 'fs' 'filesize'  )
   DESC 'Dimensione del file'
   EQUALITY integerMatch
   ORDERING integerOrderingMatch
   SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.27 )

olcObjectClasses: ( 1000.1.2.1 NAME ( 'dir'
   DESC 'Una directory'
   MUST fn
   MAY fs
   AUXILIARY )

olcObjectClasses: ( 1000.1.2.2 NAME ( 'file'
   DESC 'Un file'
   MUST (fn $ fs)
   AUXILIARY )
```

Now I'm stuck with this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try

```
ldapadd -Q -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -f filesystem.ldif
```

This will only work if you work as root (uid=0) or via sudo and on the LDAP server direct. It connects to the LDAP server based on the user id and bypasses the normal auth methods.

This access is granted by the `olcAccess` rule

```
{0}to *  by dn.base="gidNumber=0+uidNumber=0,cn=peercred,cn=external,cn=auth" manage  by * none
```

in `olcDatabase={0}config,cn=config`.

To allow access in the "normal" way, you can add the following lines to `olcDatabase={0}config,cn=config`:

```
olcRootDN: cn=admin,cn=config
olcRootPW: <yourpassword>
```

where `<yourpassword>` should be pre-encrypted via `slappasswd`.

Comment: Just fantastic, thanks! It worked. But is there a way to grant access to my cn=admin,cn=config? Should I modify some configuration files?

Comment: @coldSense: See my edit for infos on that.

Comment: And it works again! Actually on my system it is olcDatabase={0}config.ldif it seems but it works this way.

Very helpful, thanks!

Comment: Glad it helped. One more hint though: This sounds like you edited the ldif files containing the `cn=config` tree directly. Be careful with this and use it only(**!!!**) if you have lost access due to changes you did and while `slapd` is stopped to avoid damages to these files. The normal way to modify the configuration is to create appropriate ldif files and feed them to the system via `ldapmodify`. However, I use this only to create the admin password and use Apache Directory Studio for all subsequent changes afterwards.

Comment: Good point. In the future I will use ldapmodify as superuser to change configurations. Now I'm only practicing, to understand how OpenLDAP works.

Comment: `To allow access in the "normal" way, you can add the following lines` could you please share an LDIF file with these commands?

Comment: I found this helpful, too: https://www.cyrill-gremaud.ch/how-to-add-new-schema-to-openldap-2-4/