# ldap change schema and config password

Tags: ldap, fedora, openldap, fedora-20

I installed openldap server to fedora 20,
and try use it for manage bugzilla accounts.
So I first configure it for my domain, plus set password:

```
dn: olcDatabase={0}config,cn=config
changetype: modify
replace: olcRootPW
olcRootPW: {SSHA}...

dn: olcDatabase={2}hdb,cn=config
changetype: modify
replace: olcRootPW
olcRootPW: {SSHA}...
-
replace: olcRootDN
olcRootDN: cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com
-
replace: olcSuffix
olcSuffix: dc=example,dc=com
```

and run:

```
 ldapmodify -a -Q -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -f ./initial.ldif
```

After that I try add test user:

```
# User account
dn: uid=user1,ou=people,dc=example,dc=com
cn: User Name
givenName: Name
sn: User
uid: user1
mail: email@domain
objectClass: top
objectClass: inetOrgPerson
objectClass: organizationalPerson
objectClass: person
userPassword: {CRYPT}*
```

and call ldapadd

```
ldapadd -v -v -f ./useradd.ldif -x -D "cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com" -w pass
```

But it failed, say that it doesn't know inetOrgPerson.

So I try to append scheme with such class:

```
ldapadd -v -f ./inetorgperson.ldif -x -D "cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com" -w pass
```

but it failed with message about wrong login/password,

and **now** problems start:

I thought that problem that cn=config and I use cn=admin (it is my first day with ldap),
so I used:

dn: olcDatabase={0}config,cn=config
   changetype: modify
   replace: olcRootDN
   olcRootDN: cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com

and **whoa** 
    ldapadd -v -f ./inetorgperson.ldif -x -D "cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com" -w pass
start works, **but**
useradd failed with:

> ldap_add: No such object (32)

plus after restart of slapd I got:

> can only be set when rootdn is under suffix

So can anybody can give me advise how to add to fresh openldap record about user
with "uid", "mail" and passwords fields?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved problem. Theare two problems:
1)How to add schema?
Thanks to [OpenLDAP cannot add new schema](https://serverfault.com/questions/585111/openldap-cannot-add-new-schema)
I solved it by using "-Y external" for ldapadd

2)initial configuration, there is
olcDatabase={1}monitor,cn=config
it should be also changed to got working slapd.